# samsung NP305V5A power adapter stops working at boot screen, shuts down unexpectedly while running

Tags: 12.04, ati, wubi, samsung, overheating

I am new to Ubuntu. I have installed wubi.exe for 12.04 LTS on my D: drive. Problem is when the login screen comes up at booting, my power adapter dies. If I unplug and plug it again immediately, it doesn't work. It only starts working when I plug it back after like 5 minutes. Another problem I am getting is my computer heats up a LOT while running Ubuntu. And after running for a while it shuts down unexpectedly. I am not sure if it is for the temperature sensor, because I did install lm-sensor the last time. Still it crashed.

My laptop is Samsung, Windows 7, Processor: AMD-A6-3410 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics, 6GB RAM

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You may want to add your laptop model in your question title so people are made aware of model-specific to look for issues you may have.

Comment: Added the model.